# Crystal reports error, REPORT HAS NO TABLES

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

i am trying to create and fill crystal report via code but an error occurred,
***REPORT HAS NO TABLES***
but when i try to extract data from DATASET then it shows exact data,no problem but doesn't work for Crystal report.

CODE:

```
protected void Dataset_load() 
{
    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand("select * from Login", sqlcon);
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCom);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("CRDataSet");

    try
    {
        sqlcon.Open();
        //sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlDA.Fill(ds,"Login");

        ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
        rd.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt").ToString());
        rd.SetDataSource(ds.Tables["Login"]);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;


    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Response.Write(exc.Message);
    }
    finally 
    {
        sqlcon.Close();
    }
```

Comment: At first glance I see that you didn't add any tables to your DataSet.

Comment: i have already filled Dataset with table

sqlDA.Fill(ds,"Login");
Login is a table name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the tables to the dataset before you fill it.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("CRDataSet");
ds.Tables.Add(datatable);
```